# Google analytics and dynamic pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have a (Symfony based) website. I would LIKE to analyize the site traffic using Google Analytics. My site is divided into several (i.e. N) categories, each of which may have 0 to M sub categories.

Schematically, the taxonomy of the site breaks down into something like this:

1. N major categories
2. Each major category may have 0 to M sub categories

further nesting is possible, but I have just kept it simple for the purpose of illustration.

I need to know which sections of the website are genererating more traffic, so that I can concentrate my efforts on those sections. My question is:

Is there anyway to identify the data that is being generated from the different sections of my site?.

Put another way, is there a code or 'tag' that I can generate dynamically (in each page that is being monitored) and pass to GA, so that I can identify which section of the website the traffic came from?

The [documentation](http://www.google.co.uk/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=55504) I found on google about this topic was not very useful (atleast it did not answer this question).

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a uri to _trackPageview that would permit you to log the request in whatever format you'd like, including however your user's requesting the page.

Remove/replace the original call to pageTracker._trackPageview with the following:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/topcategory/subcategory');
```

You'd just need to plug in the topcategory and subcategory info. If the info is available in the URL you could parse it out using js on the fly.

Comment: nbrew: Could you point me to the part in the documentation please, so I can read it and see if I can use this solve my problems (also to see if there are any gotchas- since the example I gave was necessarily simplistic)

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply! You've probably found this but:

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55520

Note that even though they're talking about Flash it works for any type of resource.